# How to detect CTCSS?

Tags: detection

Lets say I have an audio source and I want to enable a digital output when a sub-audible CTCSS tone is present at 100Hz. How can I electronically achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, it was done with a PLL-based tone detector IC along with some analog support components.

Nowadays, it could be done with a little bit of DSP firmware running on pretty much any microcontroller.